# JavaScript copy value in key of Obj2 to Obj1

Tags: javascript, json

I have 2 Object and I need to copy value from Obj2 to Obj1 by use old key in Obj1

```
Obj1 = [{                                  Obj2 = [{
 'value': 'abc',                            'id' = '123',
 'label': 'cde',                            'name' = 'zzz',
   'childs': [{                              'categorys': [{
    'value': 'ccc',                            'id' = '555',
    'label': 'eee',                            'name' = 'yyy',
   }],                                       }],
}],                                        }]
```

I need result is

```
Obj1 = [{
 'value': '123'
 'label': 'zzz'
  childs: [{
   'value': '555'
   'label': 'yyy'
  }]
}]
```

how to do it. Im new in javascript 
Thank you

Comment: Obj1 is an array in your case. So do sth like that: Obj1[0].value = Obj2[0].id and so on...

Comment: Is there something that you tried and it didn't work, before posting this query?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not 100% on what you are trying to do as it seems that what you wrote is not actually proper code. Since you are new to JS you might not know that (most) browsers have a developer console that you can use as a testing environment. [Example](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/).

Below I re-wrote your code to use proper JS objects and to also take the ID from Obj2 and place it in Obj1. Note that I defined Obj2 first so that it would exist when I do the key value transfer.

```
var Obj2 = {
    'id': '123',
    'name': 'zzz',
    'categorys': {
        'id': '555',
        'name': 'yyy'
    }
}
var Obj1 = {
    'value': Obj2.id,
    'label': 'cde',
    'childs': {
        'value': 'ccc',
        'label': 'eee',
    },
};
```

Edit, please do comment if anything here is confusing or if I can better answer your question. Happy to help!